# when i copy and Paste text it in text-angular getting issue

Tags: angularjs, textarea, textangular

Text contains info includes bold,italic and etc.,
when i copy text(it includes double quotes like:"hey hi") and paste it in text-angular,while displaying text is fine.in console i can double-quotes in place of &#34.This &#34 created as hashtag.
when i enter manually in text-angular text &#34.Hash tag is not creating 
And my app has one more feature called as hashtag.

Example log info:

```
<p>&#34;test from web&#34;</p>
```

original text:
"test from web"

The library which am using is https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular